# toggle chrome extension on/off

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have an Extension that injects css to some websites I need to have an popup where I can toggle if the extention injects the css or not. So if it's toggled on my stylesheet should be injected and if toggled off It needs to stop injecting css so page looks like normal again.

This is the css that needs to be aplied

```
div.answerrow {
position: static !important;
clip: auto !important;
```

}

```
.solution-layer {
display: block !important;
clip: auto !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chrome.Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) api to save the state of the toggle.  Then in your content script, have javascript load the status of the toggle by what is stored in local storage.  If you toggle to a different state, just save the state again with the chrome api.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I don't know how to load different css, I have never had to change css depending on a state before

Comment: It's not that hard
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: Basically, you want in your content script to load the state of the toggle using the chrome storage api.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the css of my html from my popup, I want to swap the stylesheet that's used to inject css in to a website example: When I press the button it changes the background to black and when I press again (or an other button) it changes the background back to normal. CAUTION: the stylesheet that I want to swap is not the css from the popup.html but the one I wand to inject!!!

Thank you for helping me!!

Comment: You should be able to change the javascript context to apply your script to.

Comment: I will try your method thank you

but?

do you know if it's posible to redifine values in my manifest.json? that would be easy then because it  means that I can just change "css": ["on.css"] to "css": ["off.css"]

Comment: yes, it will be something of the sort 
var test = document.getElementIdBy('id_name').style = none

Something like that.

I would first work out of the chrome console.  Work there until you can verify that your script will do what you ask want it todo, then put it in your chrome extension script.  But get it working in the chrome console first.

Comment: Also, add another page like test.js.  In here, have your code that will load the toggle state from the stored variables in the chrome storage api.  Then based on what the state of the toggle code, set the css accordingly.